# Adb pull without creating pulled folder

Tags: android, adb

I want to pull a folder from the sdcard and put it contents inside a folder
but when I do :
`adb pull -a /sdcard/child/ B:/father/`
it creates a folder called "child" inside the folder "father" and in the "child" folder it has the content that i want to be inside the "father".

( it pull the content to : B:/father/child/ instead B:/father/ )

already tried :
`adb pull -a /sdcard/child/ "B:/father/"
adb pull -a /sdcard/child/ B:\father\`

Thx in advance

( and already tried without the "-a" )

Comment: is the answer below helping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy all the content of `father` into `child` folder you can use the following command:

```
adb pull /sdcard/child/. B:/father/
```

Hope this helps.